# In python3 is there a way to type hint method/attributes of a MagicMock object to also be MagicMock?

Tags: python, python-unittest, type-hinting

Let's say I have a class A in Python:

```py
class A():
   def func_1(...):
      ....
```

If I configure `mock_a: Union[A, MagicMock] = MagicMock()`, then in IDE I will have both methods from class A and MagicMock available in autocompletion:

```py
mock_a.func_1....
mock_a.assert_called_once_with...
```

However, is there a way to annotate/configure such that `mock_a.func_1` is also a type `MagicMock` so methods from `MagicMock` can also be populated when I type `mock_a.func_1`?

```py
mock_a.func_1.assert_called_once_with(...)
```

Comment: `assert isinstance(mock_a.func_1, MagicMock)`